# Send sms using details inside repeater code in C# on button click

Tags: c#, repeater, sms-gateway

I have a site just like just dial where I have integrated sms. Sms having some static content is sent to a user who enters a mobile number which is ok,
 but I want that the sms should contain the particular information below which the button is added to send sms. All information ans button is inside a repeater.

The same happens in just Dial which I want to do but I have no Idea to get all information in button click.

Any help is appreciated as I want to know it urgently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assing some id or random no to each button, and you can pass that button id in onclick event for ex:

onclick="ShowSMSDiv(22)"

Here 22 is the ad number. like that you can easily undustand from which section you get the hit.

Comment: how exactly I will do this please help me??

Comment: You need to write code behind logic to create a button with onclick event by passing some values in it. and in page level you need to write a javascript code to get the click event of row..